# How to Retrieve data from a SQL table based on an ID?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to familiarize myself with normalization and I've run into a problem in that I'm trying to join three tables together to create one massive SELECT which will give all the information about people in a TCustomers table, but I'm unsure how to do so. Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE TCustomers (
     CustomerID     INT             IDENTITY(1,1)   NOT NULL
    ,FirstName      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,LastName       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,City           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,[State]        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,ZipCode        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,EmailAddress   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pkCustomers PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE TLocations (
     LocationID     INT             NOT NULL
    ,LocationName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pkLocations PRIMARY KEY (LocationID)
);

CREATE TABLE TBenefitLevels (
     BenefitLevelID     INT             NOT NULL
    ,BenefitLevelName   VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL 
    ,CONSTRAINT pkBenefitLevels PRIMARY KEY (BenefitLevelID)
);

CREATE TABLE TCustomerLocationBenefits (
     CustomerID     INT             NOT NULL
    ,LocationID     INT             NOT NULL
    ,BenefitLevelID INT             NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pkCustomerLocationBenefits PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID, LocationID)
);

CREATE TABLE TCustomerStatus (
     CustomerID         INT             NOT NULL
    ,FirstOrderDate     DATE            NOT NULL
    ,NewestOrderDate    DATE            NOT NULL         
    ,CONSTRAINT pkCustomerStatus PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);
```

And I am trying to create a SELECT statement that will give me the FirstName, LastName, City, [State], ZipCode, and EmailAddress from TCustomers, the BenefitLevelName BASED on the BenefitLevelID for each Customer from TBenefitLevels, the LocationName BASED on the LocationID for each Customer from TLocations. I know this is possible, but I've completely forgotten how to do it, here is my current SELECT statement, which gets the IDs necessary, but not the Names:

```
SELECT TC.FirstName, TC.LastName, TC.City, TC.[State], TC.ZipCode, TC.EmailAddress, TL.LocationName, TBL.BenefitLevelName, TCS.FirstOrderDate, TCS.NewestOrderDate
FROM  TCustomers AS TC
     ,TLocations AS TL
     ,TBenefitLevels AS TBL
INNER JOIN TCustomerStatus AS TCS ON TC.CustomerID = TCS.CustomerID
INNER JOIN TCustomerLocationBenefits AS TCLB ON TC.CustomerID = TCLB.CustomerID
```

Currently I receive the error that "The multi-part identifier "TC.CustomerID" could not be bound. If I remove TLocations and TBenefitLevels, and replace TL.LocationName and TBL.BenefitLevelName with their respective IDs in TCLB, it does work, but not the way I want it to.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `TCustomerLocationBenefits` is what I call a bridging table, aka mapping table or relationship table as it contains the relationship between all three entities: customer, location and benefit level.

To resolve this kind of problem, you would usually start with this table as it will drive the joins for the query.

See if the query below returns what you want to see:

```
select b.FirstName, b.LastName, b.City, b.State, b.ZipCode, b.EmailAddress
    , c.BenefitLevelName
    , d.LocationName
from TCustomerLocationBenefits a
join TCustomers b                   on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
join TBenefitLevels c               on a.BenefitLevelID = c.BenefitLevelID
join TLocations d                   on a.LocationID = d.LocationID
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed! I always thought I should start with the table that had the most data, but your logic makes much more sense. Thanks a lot for the help!